# Google play multi-player, how to handle invitation if player has declined sign in before?

Tags: android

We are developing a turn based game and trying to follow google's best practices.

One rule is that to **Remember if players declined signing-in**.

```
If the player declines to sign in when your game initially starts the sign-in flow (for example, if they clicked Cancel in the sign-in UI), you should still allow the player to proceed with gameplay.

When the player launches your game again, don't invoke the sign-in flow automatically. This saves players from having to repeatedly decline signing in whenever they start your game.

One exception is if players are trying to access a gameplay feature that is dependent on being signed-in (for example, starting a multiplayer match). In this case, prompt them to sign in before continuing with gameplay.
```

Say if a user has explically signed out, and then try to receive a invitation when the app is closed, we cannot handle the invitation properly because auto sign-in has been disabled. We checked how to [handle invitations](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#handling_invitations), but fail to see any way to handle it without sign in. As far as we know, Play Games services notifies the invitees via the [ConnectionCallbacks.onConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#onConnected%28android.os.Bundle%29) method which is called only after the user has signed in.

So is there a way to tell if the game launches from invitation or just from the desktop without sign in? If not, is that mean that we cannot go with this best practice **Remember if players declined signing-in**?

Thanks in advance.